# R formula of type y ~ x + trend or y ~ x + "trend", where trend/"trend" is used as an indicator?

Tags: r

I have a model building function which uses formula to define the model. In addition to usual regression case where the formula is of type `y ~ x`, I would like to add possibility to add for example trend component as an explanatory variable, which will be defined inside of the function. Here's an example:

```
modelx <- function(formula, data,...) {        

    mf <- mc <- match.call()                         
    mf <- mf[c(1L,  match(c("formula", "data"), names(mf), 0L))]
    formula_vars <- all.vars(formula)
    if ("trend" %in% formula_vars) {
       trend <- TRUE
       formula <- update.formula(formula, ~. - trend)
    } else trend <- FALSE        

    mf[[2L]] <- formula
    mf[[1L]] <- as.name("model.frame")
    mf$na.action <- as.name("na.pass")
    mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())        
    y <- model.response(mf, "numeric")
    mt <- attr(mf, "terms")      
    X <- model.matrix(mt, mf)

    # y, X and possible trend component etc. are combined into the model object
   if(trend)
     X<-cbind(X,1:length(y))    #just an example
   list(y=y,X=X)
}
```

Here the idea is that the formula is of type  `y ~ x + trend`, and function checks if a variable called `trend` is in the formula, removes it and turns flag `trend` into `TRUE`, which it will later use in order to build appropriate trend component for the model.

I am wondering is there a better way of accomplishing this? The small problem with this approach is that there could be variable with name trend which the user wants to use and it gets mixed with model's trend component, and another problem is that for example this type of functions do not work as variable `trend` does not exist:

```
combn(c(trend,x1,x2),m=2,modelx,y=y)
```

If, instead of `trend` I use string `"trend"`, the problem is that `all.vars(formula)` does not capture character strings.

Any suggestions how to deal this type of formulas, or any pointers to some functions which have formulas which contain this type of possibilities?

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems like the most obvious thing to do is to give your `modelx` function a `trend` argument that will be given either `TRUE` or `FALSE` values, then you don't need to muck around with formulas.

Comment: True, my example is bit too simplistic. In my real application I have several these types of indicators, so I feel that it would be more user friendly to define the model as `xmodel(y~x+ind1+ind2+ind3)` instead of `xmodel(y~x,ind1=ind1,ind2=ind2,ind3=ind3)`.

Comment: I can sort of see that, but you're making a lot of hard work for yourself just so you can achieve the dubious goal of cramming arguments into a formula specification. The arguments (because that's what they are) get extracted back out of the formula specification and turned back into arguments/flags almost immediately.

Comment: You might be right that it is lot's of hard work for pretty much nothing, but I'm still interested could this functionality even be done in any reasonable way.

Comment: @Hemmo one solution is to coerce your formula by a to a string (paste, collapse) and parse it. ( to detect strings varaibles)

Comment: one common trick in this case is to name the trend variable something like `.trend` or `..trend`, which is much less likely to conflict with a user's  variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using `reshape2`

```
  unlist(reshape2:::parse_formula(y~x+'trend'))
[[1]]
y

[[2]]
x

[[3]]
[1] "trend"
```